# $7$ different keys on my circular key-ring, number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I have $7$ different keys: $2$ for my house, $2$ for my car, and $3$ for my office. I want to place these keys on a keyring such that the house keys are next to each other and the car keys are next to each other. In how many ways can I place the keys on the keyring? (Rotations and flips of the keyring don't change the arrangement.)

What I got so far: Count the house and car as one each, they are fixed. So there's now three office keys remaining to place. The possibilities now...

1. House and car next to each other, so the remaining $3$ are in a row, there's $3!  = 6$ possibilities for that.
2. A $2-1$ split between the house-car divide, again there's $3! = 6$ possibilities for that.

So there's a total of $6 + 6 = 12$ ways. My sense is I didn't overcount since flips of the keyring don't change the arrangement. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the question, all keys are different.

House keys must be together and so must be the car keys. Office keys do not have restrictions.

We start by first placing house keys together in the key ring. We need to now arrange $3$ office keys and a set of car keys. That can be done in $4!$ ways.

But house keys can be arranged within, in two ways, and similarly car keys.

Therefore total number of arrangements $ = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4! = 96$

But it is a keyring so it can be flipped. If arrangements from flips are not counted as new, we divide by $2$.

That leads to $48$.

Just a footnote, the question does not state and so I assume that keys are symmetric otherwise many keys have grooves only on one side. That would lead to many more arrangements as each such key then can be placed in the keyring in two ways.

Comment: I want to ask something , firstly , I thought this like round table question , but my answer is a little different such that place firstly $3$ office keys by $(3-1)!=2!$.After that , select $3 $ places for house keys and interchange them by $2!$ . After that , we obtain $4$ places for car keys and interchange them by $2$!. Result =$$2 \times 3 \times 2 \times 4 \times 2 = 96$$ . Moreover, divide them by $2$ , so it is $48$ . I hesitated because you treated the car and house keys are like beads in the beginning. So , is my aprroach correct . See next comment..

Comment: In other words , after i solve the question like round table and divide it by $2$ at the end is true ?

Comment: Moreover , if we said that we want to arrange $5$ women and $5$ men such that no same gender together in a keyring , is the solution like $$\frac{4! \times 5!}{2}$$

Comment: @leonard your solution is perfectly find too. I started with house keys. You are starting with office keys and then using spaces between them to place house keys and then find spaces between to place car keys. That works too.

Comment: @leonard on your last comment, I am not sure what you mean by men and women on a keyring. If you are placing $5$ distinct office keys and $5$ distinct house keys in a key ring such that no two house keys or office keys are together, it is $4! \times 5!$ arrangements. If any new arrangement by a flip is not to be considered, we divide by $2$. The question of a flip does not arise when people are seated on a round table.

Comment: yeah i meant $5$ distinct house and $5$ distinct office key. I wanted just to make question different but i seem ridiculous :) .Then , if they are on a keyring the answer $$\frac{4! \times 5!}{2}$$ . However , i did not understand that what you meant saying "if any new arrangements by a flip is not to be considered" . Then , is there any situation where the arrangements on keyring is not same and do not need to divide by $2$

Comment: @leonard take letters $A \ B \ C$ and digits $1 \ 2 \ 3$. Write them on a circle as $A \ B \ C$ on the left and $1 \ 2 \ 3$ on the right. Now if you flip, what happens? You get $1 \ 2 \ 3$ on the left and $A \ B \ C$ on the right, correct? If we need to consider this as a new arrangement then the answer will be $2! \times 3!$ just like we were arranging men and women on a round table otherwise we divide by $2$. The question here states that they should not be considered new arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

There are $3$ types of keys, because house keys must be next to each other, so do car keys, so we can think of them as two blocks, $H$ and $C$.

Because there is no restriction on office keys, we have $O1,O2,O3$. Now we have $5$ keys, $H,C,O1,O2,O3$. There are $5!$ permutations.

Because of the rotational symmetry, we should divide by $5$(Rotation symmetry means that we can rotate the arrangement $5$ times. We consider these $5$ arrangements as one arrangement.), because of the reflective symmetry, we should divide by $2$.
there are $\frac{5!}{5*2} = 12$ ways

Finally, $H$ has $2$ ways and $C$ has $2$ ways. $12 *4 = 48$ ways in total.